# drop down menu css not working, inner div not displaying

Tags: css

When hovering over `Choose Location`  the div `adv_cities` should be displayed and i can navigate the `adv_cities` menu.  What i've tried isn't working.

```
 <div class="header_top_location">  <ul id="city_nav" class="city_nav menu">
            <li class="mega"><a href="#">Choose Location</a>
                <div class="adv_cities" id="adv_cities" style="display:none">
                <ul><li>London</li>
                        <li>Bristol</li>
                        <li>Manchester</li>
                        <li>Kent</li>

            </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        </div>
```

The CSS

```
  .header_top_location .mega > a:hover + .adv_cities, .header_top_location .adv_cities:hover .adv_cities{
  display:block !important;
}
.header_top_location .adv_cities {
  background-color:#fff
}
.header_top_location .adv_cities ul{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.header_top_location .adv_cities li{
  float:left;padding:10px;
}
```

How do i solve this?

The `city_nav` code is from a plugin and i use on multiple pages, so i don't want to change the code since i use in multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want on your drop down menu is to hover over one list iten to display the submenu, then you dont necessarily need the inner div and stuff... here is a code snippet for you to work with...

```css
.mega:hover > .adv_cities {
  display: block !important;
}
.header_top_location .adv_cities {
  background-color: #fff
}
.header_top_location .adv_cities ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header_top_location .adv_cities li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_top_location">
  <ul id="city_nav" class="city_nav menu">
    <li class="mega"><a href="#">Choose Location</a>
      <div class="adv_cities" id="adv_cities" style="display:none">
        <ul>
          <li>London</li>
          <li>Bristol</li>
          <li>Manchester</li>
          <li>Kent</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

The only changes I made in css are in the 1st 3 lines... and I removed the extra div that IMO was not needed..

hope this helps

Comment: The inner div is from a wordpress plugin code.  Is this still possible with the inner div?

Comment: @user892134 - i edited the code snippet to include an inner div... does that work for you?